# Jackrabbit Clustering Configuration

Tags: lucene, embedding, cluster-computing, jackrabbit

My application uses stand alone version of jackrabbit and we wanted to move to embedded mode so that we can cluster it.

I read the requirements on the jackrabbit clustering site but still confused. Should I be having different home directories for each cluster node. i.e. If I need to configure two nodes, do I need to have `~/node1/repository.xml` and `~/node2/repository.xml`? Or they can share same `~/node/repository.xml`?

Comment: My confusion is the same :) Did you managed to find a nice step by step guide / tutorial for configuring jackrabbit clustering?

Comment: Hi, I asked part of your questions again in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183179/clustering-with-jackrabbit but I already have a working cluster - so maybe one of my posted links or configuration can help you

Answer (score 3):

[As described in the Clustering Overview](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/Clustering#Overview), "each cluster node needs its own (private) repository directory, including repository.xml file, workspace FileSystem and Search index."

Comment: And what happens if FileSystem points to shared database? Can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076020/clustering-pentaho-c-e-5-x-with-jackrabbit-repository?

Comment: If the FileSystem points to shared database, then you probably get a problem.