# Clustering with Jackrabbit

Tags: java, content-management-system, jackrabbit, hippocms, jsr170

I am about to get started with **clustering a jackrabbit repository** run by **hippocms** in the **community version**. I got it up and running but some parts of configuration I don't understand.

I understood the **concept of clustering** jackrabbit this way: You have e.g. two instances with two local repositories which get synched by a rocket-scienced journal via a shared database, but every node is using it's local repository.

After reading the following pages I ended up with the following configuration.

**Links:**

- http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/Clustering
- http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/jackrabbit/trunk/jackrabbit-core/src/test/resources/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/cluster/repository-h2.xml?view=co&content-type=text/plain
- http://greymeister.net/blog/2011/11/28/jackrabbit-clustering-primer.html

**Info:** 
*sharedRepositoryDS* points to a shared database
*repositoryDS* points to the local database (on each node)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Repository PUBLIC
        "-//The Apache Software Foundation//DTD Jackrabbit 1.5//EN"
        "http://jackrabbit.apache.org/dtd/repository-1.5.dtd">

<Repository>

    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DbFileSystem">
        <param name="url" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/sharedRepositoryDS"/>
        <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
        <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="repository_"/>
        <param name="schema" value="mysql"/>
    </FileSystem>

    <Security appName="Jackrabbit">
        <SecurityManager
                class="org.hippoecm.repository.security.SecurityManager"/>
        <AccessManager
                class="org.hippoecm.repository.security.HippoAccessManager"/>
        <LoginModule
                class="org.hippoecm.repository.security.HippoLoginModule"/>
    </Security>

    <Workspaces rootPath="${rep.home}/workspaces" defaultWorkspace="default"/>

    <Workspace name="${wsp.name}">
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DbFileSystem">
            <param name="url" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/repositoryDS"/>
            <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_"/>
            <param name="schema" value="mysql"/>
        </FileSystem>

        <PersistenceManager
                class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.MySqlPersistenceManager">
            <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
            <param name="url" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/sharedRepositoryDS"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_"/>
            <param name="externalBLOBs" value="true"/>
            <param name="consistencyCheck" value="false"/>
            <param name="consistencyFix" value="false"/>
        </PersistenceManager>

        <SearchIndex class="org.hippoecm.repository.FacetedNavigationEngineImpl">
            <param name="indexingConfiguration" value="indexing_configuration.xml"/>
            <param name="indexingConfigurationClass"
                   value="org.hippoecm.repository.query.lucene.ServicingIndexingConfigurationImpl"/>
            <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
            <param name="useCompoundFile" value="true"/>
            <param name="minMergeDocs" value="1000"/>
            <param name="volatileIdleTime" value="10"/>
            <param name="maxMergeDocs" value="1000000000"/>
            <param name="mergeFactor" value="5"/>
            <param name="maxFieldLength" value="10000"/>
            <param name="bufferSize" value="1000"/>
            <param name="cacheSize" value="100000"/>
            <param name="enableConsistencyCheck" value="true"/>
            <param name="autoRepair" value="true"/>
            <param name="analyzer"
                   value="org.hippoecm.repository.query.lucene.StandardHippoAnalyzer"/>
            <param name="queryClass" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.QueryImpl"/>
            <param name="respectDocumentOrder" value="false"/>
            <param name="resultFetchSize" value="100"/>
            <param name="extractorPoolSize" value="0"/>
            <param name="extractorTimeout" value="100"/>
            <param name="extractorBackLogSize" value="100"/>
            <param name="excerptProviderClass"
                   value="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.DefaultHTMLExcerpt"/>
            <!-- supportHighlighting value is ignored, see REPO-711 -->
            <param name="supportHighlighting" value="false"/>

            <param name="supportSimilarityOnStrings" value="true"/>
            <param name="supportSimilarityOnBinaries" value="false"/>
            <param name="slowAlwaysExactSizedQueryResult" value="false"/>

            <param name="onWorkspaceInconsistency" value="log"/>
            <!-- optional cache parameters for faceted engine. The default size
            when not configured is 1000 for both parameters -->
            <!-- param name="docIdSetCacheSize" value="1000"/>
            <param name="facetValueCountMapCacheSize" value="1000"/-->
        </SearchIndex>

        <ISMLocking
                class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.FineGrainedISMLocking"/>
    </Workspace>

    <Versioning rootPath="${rep.home}/version">
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DbFileSystem">
            <param name="url" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/repositoryDS"/>
            <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="version_"/>
            <param name="schema" value="mysql"/>
        </FileSystem>

        <PersistenceManager
                class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.MySqlPersistenceManager">
            <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
            <param name="url" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/sharedRepositoryDS"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="version_"/>
            <param name="externalBLOBs" value="true"/>
            <param name="consistencyCheck" value="false"/>
            <param name="consistencyFix" value="false"/>
        </PersistenceManager>
        <ISMLocking
                class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.FineGrainedISMLocking"/>
    </Versioning>

    <DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.db.DbDataStore">
        <param name="url" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/sharedRepositoryDS"/>
        <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
        <param name="databaseType" value="mysql"/>
        <param name="minRecordLength" value="1024"/>
        <param name="maxConnections" value="5"/>
        <param name="copyWhenReading" value="true"/>
    </DataStore>

    <Cluster id="node1" syncDelay="2000">
        <Journal class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.journal.DatabaseJournal">
            <param name="revision" value="${rep.home}/revision.log" />
            <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
            <param name="url" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/sharedRepositoryDS"/>
            <param name="databaseType" value="mysql"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="journal_"/>
        </Journal>
    </Cluster>
</Repository>
```

Questions:

1. Is the configuration correct?
2. What is the repository.FileSystem ?
3. Whats the difference to the repository.Workspace.FileSystem ?
4. The PersistenceManager is responsible for writing the data, but why should it write into the shared database? (I want to get rid of this bottleneck right?)

**Database Tables**
This is what the local node database looks like (for my taste a little too little):
[image]

This is what the shared database looks like:
[image]

Comment: Talking to some people who are using the enterprise licence it comes out the configuration I posted here is only a little different from the one hippo uses in enterprise projects. So I guess using my configuration puts you on a valid path.

Answer (score -4):

Clustering support for Hippo is for the enterprise edition and it's best to reach us at sales@onehippo.com for detailed answers for your specific case.